# Writing 3 functions to convert feet and inches to meters and centimeters in C++?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to write a C++ program that consists of 3 functions one for input , one for the calculation and one for output . The program is supposed to take feet and inches as input then print the converted value of meters and centimeters back to the user . I think there's something wrong with calling by reference since i'm still learning how to use it properly , anyways here's the code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void input(double feet , double inches);
void calc(double &feet , double &inches);
void output(double &feet , double &inches);
void main()
{
 double feet1 , inches1;
 char ans;
 do
 {
  input(feet1,inches1);
  calc(feet1,inches1);
  output(feet1,inches1);
  cout<<"Would you like to calculate again? y/n : ";
  cin>>ans;
 }
 while(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
}
void input(double feet , double inches)
{
 cout<<"Enter feet : ";
 cin>>feet;
 cout<<"Enter inches : ";
 cin>>inches;
}
void calc(double &feet , double &inches)
{
 double meters , centimeters;
 meters = feet * 0.3048;
 centimeters = inches * 2.54;
}
void output(double &feet , double &inches)
{
 calc(feet,inches);
 cout<<"Converted feet to metres : "<<metres;
 cout<<"Converted inches to centimeters : "<<centimeters;
}
```

Comment: Make it `void input(double& feet , double& inches)`

Comment: Also, calc doesn't return anything.

Comment: You have added `functional-programming` to the tags. Yet your program is entirely procedural. Also, please indent your code.

Answer (score 3):

You have (at least) three problems: The first is that you modify the arguments passed to the `input` function, but as arguments are passed by value (i.e. copied) you are only modifying the copies. You need to pass the arguments by reference (which you do with the other functions, even when you don't need it for them).

The second problem is that in your `calc` function you declare `meters` and `centimeters` as local variables. Once the function returns those variables goes out of scope and can't be referenced from anywhere else.

The third problem, and this should give you a compilation error, is that you try to use `metres` (check spelling, it's not the same as in `calc`) and `centimeters` from the output function, and there those variables are not declared.

Comment: +1, even though (unfortunately) our American colleagues like to use `meter` etc.

Comment: So you're saying i have to make the first function have call by reference arguments but for the other 2 functions i should keep use pass by value? Also how can i fix the second problem you mentioned?      
Thanks :)

Comment: @KareemYoussef Regarding the arguments, yes that's correct. As for the second and third problem, the simple solution is to make these variables global. A better solution might be to have to more (reference) arguments to `calc` to "return" these variables, and then pass them as simple (non-reference) arguments to `output`.

Comment: I made calc a call by reference function but when i made the variables centimeters and meters global the output is 0 for both of them .

Comment: @KareemYoussef The (global) variables are zero because you are still declaring them again in the `calc` function, which will shadow the global variables. Don't declare them locally.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're pairing feet with meters and inches with centimetres is going to get you in a tangle: for various conversions you'll end up with inches greater than 12 or centimetres greater than 100.

If I were you I'd maintain only two variables - metres and feet - and apply the conversion between those. **Then you can drop the references altogether** as the conversion functions will return a single values.

Then, to convert feet to feet and inches you can use

`(int)feet`

for the feet part

`(feet - (int)feet) * 12`

for the inches part.

Answer (score 0):

```
void input(double feet , double inches);
```

As you want to change feet and inches, you can use references like you have done in other function.

```
void calc(double &feet , double &inches)
```

In this function you change local "meters" and "centimeters" but it's lost when leaving the function.
Also you do nothing with feet and inches so you don't need references.
You can change it with something like that :

```
void calc(const double feet , const double inches, double &meters, double &centimeters)
```

And now you can call this function with "input" data (feet, inches) and "output" (meters, centimeters).

In output function,I'm not sure if you want to call calc inside it or if it is a mistake (as calc function is also called in main/while loop)
but in output function you need to give it meter and centimeter. OR as it is so calc give you data you need but don't call calc in the do-while loop.

other things:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

One time is enough.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```